# How to solve is_hidden error of choicefield in Django model forms?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am wokring on a form to save data where *from and to days* are choice fields in models.py. So I make my form Model in forms.py be choice fields. I've done this far.

## models.py

```
class Create_Class(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=1)
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    from_choice = (
        ('Mon', 'Monday'),
        ('Tue', 'Tuesday'),
        ('Wed', 'Wednesday'),
        ('Thu', 'Thursday'),
        ('Fri', 'Friday'),
        ('Sat', 'Saturday'),
        ('Sun', 'Sunday'),
    )
    from_days = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=from_choice)
    to_days = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=from_choice)
    from_time = models.TimeField()
    to_time = models.TimeField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

## forms.py

```
class Create_Class_Model_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Create_Class
        exclude = ['created_by', 'created_on']
        fields = ['class_name', 'from_days', 'to_days', 'from_time', 'to_time']
        from_choice = (
            ('Mon', 'Monday'),
            ('Tue', 'Tuesday'),
            ('Wed', 'Wednesday'),
            ('Thu', 'Thursday'),
            ('Fri', 'Friday'),
            ('Sat', 'Saturday'),
            ('Sun', 'Sunday'),
        )
        widgets = {
            'class_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'from_days': forms.ChoiceField(choices=from_choice, widget=forms.ChoiceWidget),
            'to_days': forms.ChoiceField(choices=from_choice, widget=forms.Select()),
            'from_time': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'to_time': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

## Views.py

```
def Class_create(request):
    form = Create_Class_Model_Form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.created_by = request.user.username
        obj.save()
        print('successful')
        messages.success(request, 'Saved Successfully')
    c_names = Name_of_classes.objects.values('name')
    templatename = 'genius/class_create.html'
    context = {'form': form, 'c_names': c_names}
    return render(request, templatename, context)
```

## Error

```
ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'
```

**The error is from forms.py**

Your help to solve this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ChoiceField is not a widget. Just add it as a field and it should work.

```
class Create_Class_Model_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    from_days = forms.ChoiceField(choices=<the choices>)
    to_days = forms.ChoiceField(choices=<the choices>)

   class Meta:
      ....
```

Comment: @VikrantAgrahari nice. If you can mark my answer has the solution, it would be nice.